# Google Maps API v3 - Marker Event Listener Issue in Chrome when displaying a map zoom

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I am building a page that displays 5 small Google Maps using the Google Map API v3. Each map has a marker using a custom image and each marker bring the user to a custom URL on the click event on the marker. This part works in all browsers.

Under each of these maps, there is a "Enlarge map" link that display a zoom of the map in a "lightbox" like popup on the click event. These are actually placed in 5 hidden div that are displayed on the "Enlarge map" click event ( using $("#div").show(); ). On the click event, I also call the "resize" and "set center" events to make the display right.

In all browsers, when I click on the marker on the map zoom, it brings me to the custom url, BUT NOT IN CHROME. It's like Chrome has "flushed" the click event listener after the call of $("#div").show(); .

I also tested it with only 1 small map and 1 enlarge map link, still the same issue.

How can I fix this issue in Chrome?

Comment: do yo got any solution ?